Hibernate 6 - IN clause / binding a collection
I tried to write a search query for my shop app, it includes the usage of IN clause and binding a Set of IDs. While hardcoded values work well (like '(1, 3, 5)'), Hibernate seems unable to bind the passed collection (producersIDs).
EDIT: The 'IS NULL' check turned out to be the issue, tho it still would be nice to know why and whats an another way to handle it, for now I have:
(:emptyProducersIDs = TRUE OR p.producer.id IN :producersIDs) .setParameter("emptyProducersIDs", isEmpty(p.producersIDs()))
public List<ProductDTO> find(ProductSearchDTO p) {
    String query = "SELECT new shop.coffeenook.dto.ProductDTO(" +
            "p.name, p.description, p.euroPrice, p.producer.id, p.caffeineMilligrams, p.availableAmount) " +
            "FROM Product p " +
            "WHERE (:name IS NULL OR p.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')) " +
            "AND ((:minPrice IS NULL OR p.euroPrice >= :minPrice) " +
            "AND (:maxPrice IS NULL OR p.euroPrice <= :maxPrice)) " +
            "AND (:producersIDs IS NULL OR p.producer.id IN :producersIDs)" +
            "AND ((:minCaffeine IS NULL OR p.caffeineMilligrams >= :minCaffeine) " +
            "AND (:maxCaffeine IS NULL OR p.caffeineMilligrams <= :maxCaffeine)) " +
            "AND (:minAmount IS NULL OR p.availableAmount >= :minAmount)";
    return em.createQuery(query, ProductDTO.class)
            .setParameter("name", p.name())
            .setParameter("minPrice", p.minPrice())
            .setParameter("maxPrice", p.maxPrice())
            .setParameter("producersIDs", p.producersIDs())
            .setParameter("minCaffeine", p.minCaffeine())
            .setParameter("maxCaffeine", p.maxCaffeine())
            .setParameter("minAmount", p.minAmount())
            .getResultList();
}

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [[1]] did not match expected type [SqmBasicValuedSimplePath(shop.coffeenook.product.Product(p).producer.id)]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractCommonQueryContract.setParameter(AbstractCommonQueryContract.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.setParameter(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:140)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductRepository.find(ProductRepository.java:37)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductRepository_ClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductService.find(ProductService.java:32)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductService_ClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductResource.find(ProductResource.java:33)
    at shop.coffeenook.product.ProductResource$quarkusrestinvoker$find_5dcac52244cce907a28f72e8944faa96f5e1384d.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:599)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:11)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:11)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CoercionException: Cannot coerce value '[1]' [java.util.HashSet] to Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongJavaType.coerce(LongJavaType.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongJavaType.coerce(LongJavaType.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.coerce(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:113)

I've already tried a few things, such as an array or a list/wrapping it in braces, but nothing works.

Maybe try ((:producersIDs) IS NULL OR p.producer.id IN (:producersIDs))?
Otherwise... what's the type of p.producersIDs()?
EDIT:
I guess IS NULL is not defined on tuples ((value1, value2)).
I'm unsure how Hibernate ORM would react to a null Set as a parameter value anyway; my guess would be: not great.
Did you try IS EMPTY? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-collection-operators
((:producersIDs) IS EMPTY OR p.producer.id IN (:producersIDs))

i tried wrapping it in braces after i discovered the null check is the issue, but it doesnt work in any way. the type is a Set holding Long values.

You do not need to put brackets after IN. So in your example it will be IN :producersIDs. Also make sure that the list is not empty.
Also just for code readability, maybe do null checks on java and just concatenate the strings, in that way you will have more control over your validation as well.

im aware of everything you said, its already been implemented and i included how i now handle the null value (an empty one is already validated on the controller level), but that doesnt really help my case. it would be nice to know if its possible to directly exclude the IN statement from the query if the value is null.
